# Customising input area in material ui autocomplete

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

I am using material ui autocomplete to display partners list.  The options are listed as shown in the attached image
[image]

As you can see the options are listed in the format

```
[name]

[type]  (displayed below the name)
```

Now, when an option is selected, i need to display the selected option in the **same** format similar to the following image.
[image]

I tried the following

```
 getOptionLabel={(option) => (
    <div>
      <p>{option.name}</p>
      <p>{option.type}</p>
    </div>
 )})
```

but this doesn't work since the **getOptionLabel** is expected to return a string .

Currently the code is as follows

```
<AsyncAutocomplete
        field={form.$("partnerId")}
        fullWidth
        fetchOptions={store.getPartners}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => (
            <div>
              <p>{option.name}</p>
              <p>{option.type}</p>
            </div>
        )})
        isOptionEqualToValue={(option, value) => option.id === value.id}
        noOptionsText="Type to search"
        freeSolo={false}
        showOptionsOnOpen={false}
        renderOption={(props, partner) => (
          <PartnerOption key={partner.id} partner={partner} {...props} />
        )}
      />
```

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have customized code for you

```
<Autocomplete
    freeSolo
    id="free-solo-2-demo"
    open={true}
    options={top100Films}
    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
    renderOption={(props: object, option: any, state: object) => (
      <div
        className={`styles.option`}
        style={{ display: "block" }}
        {...props}
      >
        <p>{option.title}</p>
        <p>
          <b>{option.type}</b>
        </p>
      </div>
    )}
    renderInput={(params) => (
      <TextField
        {...params}
        label="Search input"
        InputProps={{
          ...params.InputProps,
          type: "search",
        }}
      />
    )}
  />




const top100Films = [
      { title: "Partner1", type: "Custom Broker" },
      { title: "Partner2", type: "Custom Broker" },
      { title: "Partner3", type: "Custom Broker" },
      { title: "User1", type: "Custom Broker2" },
      { title: "User2", type: "Custom Broker2" },
      { title: "User3", type: "Custom Broker2" },
    ]
```

hope it can help you

Working Demo:
[codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/withered-glitter-rgph9l)

Cheers

Comment: This does not work. The selected option in in the text field is showing only the name. It is not showing the type below the name